# Add sub-title to Products List

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm looking for adding a sub-title or a short paragraph to show under the product's name on the products list (In smaller, more subtle look) .

Preferably, the sub-title\paragraph will be taken from a new attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple add a new attribute (e.g. subtitle), add that attribute to the attribute sets for your products.  Then override the appropriate .phtml template file and add something like this:  $product->getSubtitle() where you want that text output.

Comment: Use the feature that display's the blocks (in the admin) to show you which phtml file is rendering into the page you're looking at.

Comment: I've googled it because I didn't find it on the CMS pages or Blocks. I found it on "app/design/frontend/…/…/template/catalog/product/list.phtml" and it worked.

Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 0):

We do this in our shop by defining a special character in the product name and styling anything after that character differently in the front end.

We used the ^ character and did a php string replace on that character.